# print_r array returns nested arrays

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have the following script to create an array out of my code:

```
$roundstotal=mysql_query("SELECT id FROM calendar 
                          WHERE eventDate 
                          BETWEEN '$season_start' 
                              AND '$season_end' 
                              AND competition='$compId' 
                              AND tag!='T' 
                          ORDER BY eventDate ASC", $CONNECTW);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($roundstotal)) {
    $roundsarray[]=$row;
}
```

When I try to print_r it (as `print_r($roundsarray);` ), I get the following, which is not what all the documentation about arrays I have seen shows. This could be the case why when I try to use data from the array further down the line, I get nothing.

The printout is:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 598 ) 
        [1] => Array ( [id] => 602 ) 
        [2] => Array ( [id] => 607 ) 
        [3] => Array ( [id] => 613 )  
        [4] => Array ( [id] => 619 )  
        [5] => Array ( [id] => 626 )  
        [6] => Array ( [id] => 633 )  
        [7] => Array ( [id] => 641 )  
        [8] => Array ( [id] => 648 )  
        [9] => Array ( [id] => 656 )  
        [10] => Array ( [id] => 660 )  
        [11] => Array ( [id] => 668 )  
        [12] => Array ( [id] => 675 )  
        [13] => Array ( [id] => 682 )  
        [14] => Array ( [id] => 688 )  
        [15] => Array ( [id] => 694 )  
        [16] => Array ( [id] => 699 ) )
```

Is this correct? Shouldn't it be `Array ([0] => 598 [1]=> 602` etc?

Comment: No everything is correct. If you want a one-dimensional array, just merge each row into your array.

Comment: `$roundsarray[]=$row['id'];` this much change needed in your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `mysql_*` functions have been deprecated for quite a few *years*, so do not use them. Below, I will answer using the `mysqli_*` functions.

Second, this is expected behavior, as `mysqli_fetch_assoc` already returns an associative array:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($roundstotal)) {
    // $row is an array of array("id" => 598); and so on
    $roundsarray[]=$row;
}
```

What you need is

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($roundstotal)) {
    $roundsarray[]=$row['id'];
}
```

Then `$roundsarray` array will look as you expect it to look:

```
Array (
    [0] => 598 
    [1] => 602 
    [2] => 607 
    [3] => 613
    // ... and so on
)
```